# Could not found temp table if Exit in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The SQL statement shown below used to work in previous versions, but not in SQL Server 2014:

Attempt #1:

```
IF object_id('[#TemptableName]') IS NOT NULL
    SELECT * FROM #TemptableName
ELSE 
    PRINT 'NOT FOUND'
GO
```

Attempt #2:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'#TemptableName', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
   SELECT * FROM #TemptableName
ELSE
   PRINT 'NOT FOUND'
```

I found this strange - any ideas?

Comment: When a temporary table name is specified, the database name must come before the temporary table name, unless the current database is tempdb. For example: SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytemptable').

Comment: What I find strange is that you have not explained how/why it 'does not work'. Error or unexpected outcome?

Comment: Temp tables are stored in tempdb.sys.tables. pls check in this table

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TemptableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TemptableName') IS NOT NULL
    SELECT * FROM #TemptableName
ELSE 
    PRINT 'NOT FOUND'
GO
```